# How to filter the object on typing inside the searchbar

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ionic2, searchbar

i am getting an array from back end that is used in searchbar

off course it is working fine but the problem is i am not able to filter as per the user types inside the searchbar

here is my searchbar html

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary" >
      <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" [showCancelButton]="false" ></ion-searchbar>

      <ion-list *ngIf="showList">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="searchBar(item)">
          {{ item.name }}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

here is my .ts file

```
getItems(ev) {
    // Show the results
     this.showList = true;


    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {

        //return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        return item;
      })
    } else {
      // Hide the results
      this.showList = false;
    }
  }

  onCancel(ev) { 
    // Show the results
    this.showList = false;

    // Reset the field
    ev.target.value = '';
  }
```

Comment: is the user type a type field inside a user model or the `type` of the `object`?

Comment: i have multiple objects which you can see in my html content `item` inside that i will use to display the name field only and it is working but my problem is if the user types a letter like `c` then names related c inside the array of objects should be filtered

Comment: Ok I'm preparing a plunker then.

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe to achieve this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filteritem'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        if(args !== undefined){        
          return items.filter(item => item.indexOf(args[0]) > -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can change `transform`'s implementation to change the way you want to filter your array base on the input value.

Example on this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KxGZOtPz6GLlGkUjXwqn?p=preview)

Comment: i was trying in ionic2 i am not getting the answer can you make a plunker for ionic 2

Comment: I never used ionic2, but it should work like a classic angular2 app isn't it?

Comment: check this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/ provided by the ionic team i have to make use of this you see for the demo one in the right side of the page